# Bluez 5.65 mesh-cfgclient failed genrate UUID

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi3, bluez, bluetooth-mesh

I tried to provision a device via Bluez and `mesh-cfgclient` on my Raspberry Pi.

Bluez: 5.65
Raspberry Pi: 3B+

First I am looking for provisionable devices and get:

```
Scan result:
    rssi = -38
    UUID = DDDD00000000000000000000000000DD
    OOB = 0000
    URI Hash = 00000000
```

If I am stating the provision process with:

`provision dddd00000000000000000000000000dd`

I get the error:

`Failed to generate UUID array from dddd00000000000000000000000000dd`

If I am trying this:

`provision dddd0000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000dd`

I get:

`Requires UUID`

So I don't know which UUID `mesh-cfgclient` like to get from me. Do someone know what I missed here.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm encountering this as well. I don't know if it's a new issue because this is my first foray into BLE mesh...

My findings so far has led me to the UUID needs to comply with [RFC-4122](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt).

This is my conclusion based on downloading the [bluez source](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git) (specifically 5.65), along with the [ell source](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/ell/ell.git/) (specifically 0.55) and walking through `add_node_setup`, which led me to `l_util_from_hexstring`, which seemed fine.
It was `l_uuid_is_valid` that doesn't like the format...
It's expecting the `variant` (==2) and `version` (between 1 & 5) to be included.
Mind you, when I mention those values, they are the result of bit-shifting, so variant == 0x80, and version between 0x16 and 0x80, and this is all after the UUID we are provided is converted into hexidecimal.

I haven't done it yet, but you can probably use a uuid generator online or in linux (`uuidgen`).

I will say that at the moment, I don't know why `ell` is expecting `variant` to == 2.
Looking at the RFC, section `4.1.1`, I'm not seeing any bit combination that equates to 2.
Actually, looking at the wikipedia for it, I see the UUID number 2 doesn't equate to the bit combination, but rather the zero-based position of the list, which is 110 ("Reserved, Microsoft Corporation backward compatiblity").

If we were to alter your `dddd00000000000000000000000000dd`, I *think* it might look like `dddd00000000 40 00 80 000000000000dd`.
I chose `0x40` for version 4, and 0x80 for the variant #2 mentioned earlier (bit-shifted).

Comment: Thank you for your hint.

I changed the uuid to an Version 4 UUID and now it works. Unfortunately there is an bad-pdu error while the provisioning process now, but therefore I will open an new thread.